# How mock Companion object in Android using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, junit5

I been trying to run a unite test and I am now facing some issue in mocking the Application Context. I tried mockStatic() but is not working. I am using Junit 5 and org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.6 for testing.

```
class ApplicationContext : Application() {

    init {
       instance = this
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance : ApplicationContext? = null
        fun applicationContext() : Context = instance!!.applicationContext
    }
```

When I run my test this throws a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.adaptavant.yoco.Util.ApplicationContext$Companion.applicationContext(ApplicationContext.kt:14)
    at com.adaptavant.yoco.viewModel.LoginViewModelTest.setUp(LoginViewModelTest.kt:48)
```

Can Someone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ApplicationContext` available in unit test - you need to use instrumentation tests for that:

- Local unit tests:

> Use these tests to minimize execution time when your tests have no Android framework dependencies or when you can mock the Android framework dependencies.

- Instrumented tests

> These tests have access to Instrumentation APIs, give you access to information such as the Context of the app you are testing, and let you control the app under test from your test code.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/test)

Comment: actually there is a Context for unit tests via ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() after adding android test lib